# I am both lock and key - who am I?

Tags: riddle

Enter! Small or large, as the case may be
I'll assist you - it's easy! - I'm both lock and key

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are

> The `CAPS LOCK` key

Enter! Small or large, as the case may be

> `ENTER` is another key on the keyboard. `CAPS LOCK` is used to toggle *case* between lower and upper, or *small* and *large*.
>
>
>  Author's note: in addition, the injunction "Enter! Small or large, as the case may be" can be read as an invitation to *enter* text into the computer by typing it in, in the appropriate case (lower or upper).

I'll assist you - it's easy!

> `CAPS LOCK` makes it easier to type a string of capital letters, rather than `SHIFT`.

I'm both lock and key

> *Lock* is in the name, and a *key* is what you are.

Comment: Now that you're the winner, can you expand your answer a bit? After all, with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty of editing your answer to add another small clarification note.

Comment: Doesn't "assist" me because I normally pop it off with a ruler on my keyboards to avoid my clumsy fingers hitting it :-)

Answer (score 22):

You are

> the CAPS LOCK key on a keyboard

Enter! Small or large, as the case may be

> controls character case (small or large)

I'll assist you - it's easy! - I'm both lock and key

> caps LOCK KEY

Comment: Darn!  Missed it by 4 seconds.  That's what I get for being wordy.

Comment: hahaha. I knew it would be fast, so I raced to the character limit, and then edited a few more words in. Worth it!

Comment: Nice work to both of you, and sorry I can't select both. It's a cutthroat business, puzzling...

Answer (score 19):

I know this has already been answered correctly, but I thought I would add what sprung to mind when I read the title, maybe someone will find it interesting.

---

You are

> A cipher key

Enter! Small or large, as the case may be

> A key can be small or large, depending on the circumstances. Eg. a user's password to decrypt their hard drive, or an SSH keypair used to encrypt and decrypt network transmissions which is comparatively quite large.

I'll assist you - it's easy! - I'm both lock and key

> The key(s) can be used to both encrypt and decrypt the information.

Comment: This is what I thought of as well, especially when seeing only the title in the hot network questions list.

Comment: "small or large": Cryptographic keys can be anywhere from 40-bit (export-controlled) to 128-bit (symmetric) to 2048-bit (recommended RSA)

Comment: As soon as I saw it in the HNQ, I thought "a symmetric encryption key".

Answer (score 18):

As a perhaps tongue-in-cheek alternative:

> Tom Hiddleston

Enter!

> Tom plays Loki, and who can make an entrance to rival Loki's? Nobody! So much so that there is, in fact, a LEGO/Marvel computer game called *A Loki Entrance*. Because it's a pun, you see, on "low-key".

Small or large, as the case may be

> Loki is a frost giant. That's fairly large. He can also become human sized.

I'll assist you - it's easy!

> He's a helpful guy, whether you are a big famous reporter, unicef, or just a kid [image: Loki helps with coat 1] [image: Loki helps with coat 2] [image: Loki Helps Boy 1] [image: Loki helps boy 2]

I'm both lock and key

> Loki contains "Lok" and "ki".

Who am I?

> The question requires it be a who, not a what, and therefore cannot be the caps lock key! :D

Comment: Like this one better 

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Yog-Sothoth

Because,

> Yog-Sothoth knows the gate. **Yog-Sothoth is the gate. Yog-Sothoth is the key** and guardian of the gate. Past, present, future, all are one in Yog-Sothoth. He knows where the Old Ones broke through of old, and where They shall break through again. He knows where They have trod earth's fields, and where They still tread them, and why no one can behold Them as They tread.
>  
>                 —H. P. Lovecraft, "The Dunwich Horror"

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Those blueprints from *Contact*.  Encoded within them were the instructions to read them.