# Same Riddle Different Answer: I am both lock and key - who am I?

Tags: riddle, cipher

> **NOTE:** 
> Though the body is identical to [I am both lock and key - who am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29573/i-am-both-lock-and-key-who-am-i), a different answer is expected, and thus this is **not a duplicate**. 
> Cyrnfr qb abg pybfr guvf dhrfgvba.
> Thanks!

Enter! Small or large, as the case may be

I'll assist you - it's easy! - I'm both lock and key

**Who am I?**

**HINTS:**

1

> Gur nafjre vf bs yratgu svir

2

> Weet bksa, co vhyudt, mu qhu qbb cqhhyut, unsufj oek qdt jxqj tkbb rhejxuh mxe xqhtbo sxqdwui qj qbb!

Comment: Can anyone please tell me why is this downvoted? It is my original idea of "Same riddle Different Answer" Question. Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted to counter the downvote ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All in all, @Shahriar and @rhsquared, had it all. I just joined their answer and added an explanation for hints.

---

I think the answer is

> ROT13

Enter! Small or large, as the case may be

> ROT13 can work on both "small" and "large" case

I'll assist you - it's easy! - I'm both lock and key

> ROT13 is both lock and key in the sense that a text "encrypted" with ROT13 can be decrypted by applying a new ROT13 operation.

Hint 1

> ROT13 has 5 characters

Hint 2

> "Good luck, my friend, we are all married, except you and that dull brother who hardly changes at all!" All ROTxx is "maried" with ROT[26-xx] except for ROT13 married with himself, and ROT0, who doesn't change the text at all.

Comment: Well done! Wanna upvote but couldn't, reached daily upvote limit... Will do so tmr!

Comment: sorry for this super late +1, here you go ;)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is-

> ROT13

Because-

> It's both the encryption method and decryption method for hiding plaintext.

Comment: You havent explained the first line and the second line of the body. Keep it up!

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you used:

> both Rot13 and Rot10 in you puzzle and hints I would say the answer is Rot16 in order to match the requirement for 5 letter length.

Enter! Small or large, as the case may be

> The Rotxx encryption works on both caps (large) and small letters.

I'll assist you - it's easy! - I'm both lock and key

> With the ROT encryption/decryption you can both encode and decode the text. We only need to keep in mind that only Rot13 is 'symetrical'. In all the rest the lock/key pair the sum of the Rotxx + Rotyy is 26. Considering that Hint 2 can be decoded using Rot10, I think the answer is its missing counterpart **Rot16**.

Comment: on the right track, but who in the lot am i specifically asking for? by the way, you already have all info needed. keep it up!

Comment: edited hint 2 pls check